# В чем ошибка в конфигурации Gulp?

Tags: gulp, npm

Хочу настроить свою конфигурацию Gulp'а для девелопмента с простым локальным сервером и с поддержкой watch. Также хочу попробовать livereload. Для удобства я не стал сваливать все таски в `gulpfile.js` . Я использовал плагин `require-dir` .Благодаря ему я создал в отедльной папке js-файлы. код `gulpfile.js`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var requireDir = require('require-dir');

requireDir('./gulp_tasks', { recurse: true });
```

Переходим к таскам. Под стили,картинки,разметку,скрипты, сервер и т.д. я создал отдельные файлы и записал отдельные таски.Привожу код тасков(ниже приведу скриншот древа проекта):

Таск **default**:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('default',  [ 'html', 'styles', 'scripts','fonts','images', 'connect', 'watch']);
```

Таск **html**:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    connect = require('gulp-connect'),
    reload = require('connect-livereload');

gulp.task('html', function(){
  return gulp.src('index.html')
    .on('error', console.log)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'))
    .pipe(connect.reload())
});
```

Таск **styles**:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    connect = require('gulp-connect'),
    reload = require('connect-livereload');

gulp.task('styles', function() {
  gulp.src(['src/css/*.css',
            'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
            'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'
            ])
      .on('error', console.log)
      .pipe(cleanCSS({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
      .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9'))
      .pipe(concat('styles.min.css'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'))
      .pipe(connect.reload())
});
```

Таск **scripts**:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    browserify = require('gulp-browserify'),
    connect = require('gulp-connect'),
    reload = require('connect-livereload');

gulp.task('scripts', function(){
  return gulp.src(['../src/js/**/*.js',
                   'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
                   'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'])
        .on('error', console.log)
        .pipe(browserify())
        .pipe(concat('app.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'))
        .pipe(connect.reload())
});
```

Таск **fonts**:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('fonts', function() {
  gulp.src('node_modules/bootstrap/fonts/*{ttf,woff,woff2,svg,eot}')
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/fonts'))
  gulp.src('./src/fonts/open_sans/*ttf')
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/fonts/open_sans'))
});
```

Таск **images**:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');

gulp.task('images', function() {
  gulp.src('./img/**/*')
      .pipe(imagemin())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/img'))
});
```

Таск **connect**(локальный сервер):

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    connect = require('gulp-connect');

gulp.task('connect', function () {
  connect.server({
    name: 'Dev App',
    root: ['app', 'tmp'],
    port: 3000,
    livereload: true
  });
});
```

Таск **watch**:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('watch', function () {
  var watcher1 = gulp.watch(['../*.html'], ['html']);
  watcher1.on('change', function (event) {
    console.log('Event type: ' + event.type);
    console.log('Event path: ' + event.path);
  });
  var watcher2 = gulp.watch(['src/css/*.css'], ['styles']);
  watcher2.on('change', function (event) {
    console.log('Event type: ' + event.type);
    console.log('Event path: ' + event.path);
  });
  var watcher3 = gulp.watch(['../src/js/**/*.js'], ['scripts']);
  watcher3.on('change', function (event) {
    console.log('Event type: ' + event.type);
    console.log('Event path: ' + event.path);
  });
});
```

[image: Структура проекта] Собственно с первыми тасками по разметке,стилям и скриптам проблем не возникло.Но с сервером watch и livereload не выходит. Сервер стартует,но при переходе на localhost:3000 я вижу сообщение Cannot GET /,  в консоли браузера пишет `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` 
однако системная консоль радужно выдает:

```
Dev App started http://localhost:3000
LiveReload started on port 35729
```

watch и livereload судя по всему я тоже прописал коряво. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: поменял в таске connect, root: ['app', 'tmp'], на root: './build', теперь, он рисует все. однако, watch и livreload не отрабатывают при изменении файлов...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. В случае с livereload основная проблема была из-за того,что я использовал не тот плагин. Был использован `gulp-livereload`, а нужно было `connect-livereload`(постольку,посколько муой сервер создан на базе плагина `gulp-connect`). Теперь watch и connect-livereload работают в связке. в консоли я вижу,что и когда поменялось, происходит пересборка данного файла и дальше браузер обновляет сам страничку. Шикарно. поправлю конфиг в шапке(вдруг кому пригодится...),Решение проблемы с сервером описал в комментарии к своему же вопросу.

Comment: Хотел бы поинтересоваться, почему вы не пользуйтесь https://www.browsersync.io/ ? Когда я только начал работать с gulp, тоже использовал только livereload, но потом понял, что browserSync умней и легче настраивается.

Comment: @DimenSi ответ простой-это мой первый конфиг.я не так давно работаю с гульпом и знаком еще не со всеми плагинами,также не знаю еще какой из них лучше,какой хуже

Answer (score 0):

У меня тоже подобная проблема, но листинг намного проще и всё в одном файле:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var compass = require( 'gulp-compass' );
var notify = require( 'gulp-notify' );
var livereload = require( 'connect-livereload' );
var connect = require('gulp-connect');

gulp.task('connect', function() {
 connect.server({
root: 'app',
livereload: true
 });
});

gulp.task( 'compass', function(){
gulp.src('sass/*.scss')
    .pipe(compass({
        config_file: 'config.rb',
        css: 'css',
        sass: 'sass'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
    .pipe(connect.reload());
    //.pipe(notify('Done!'));
}); 

 gulp.task('html', function(){
  gulp.src('index.html')
  .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
 gulp.watch('sass/*.scss', ['compass']);
 gulp.watch('index.html', ['html']);

});

gulp.task('default', ['connect', 'compass', 'html', 'watch']);
```

пробовал и

```
var livereload = require( 'connect-livereload' );
```

и

```
var livereload = require( 'gulp-livereload' );
```

но выдаёт всё тоже Cannot GET /

[image: скрин дерева]

Comment: изменил пути, создал папку dev скомпилировал компасс там теперь:
дерево проекта https://yadi.sk/i/Ckd0A0ht3FeSFc
гульп https://yadi.sk/i/bpUiRcS33FeSPh
и при запуске такая ошибка https://yadi.sk/i/cGjKJHtR3FeSXc

Comment: понял я в чём дело css: 'dev/css', sass: 'dev/sass' здесь надо было тоже путь поменять